# extracting two group number by Regular Expressions

Tags: java, android, regex

I have following string, I want to extracting 150 and 136 from that by using Regular Expressions in java (android studio), both number are before MB (between them exist space) and some times second number is not exist how i can extracting them 
in to separate group?

```
"Your Day Traffic is 150 MB and your Night Traffic is 136 MB "
```

and give me two group like this:

```
group 1 ==> "150"
group 2 ==> "136"
```

**Best Answer:**

after some search and try in egex101.com i found my answer:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^\\d]*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?) MB(?:[^\\d]+(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?) MB)?.*$");//. represents single character
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Your Day Traffic is 150 MB and your Night Traffic is 136 MB");

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("group 1 ==>" + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("group 2 ==>" + m.group(2));
    }
```

and i get this :

```
group 1 ==>150
group 2 ==>136
```

Comment: Your regex is unnecessary complicated. Try to find essential parts in your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex `((\d+)\sMB)` if there are one or more spaces between the number and `MB` you can use `\s+` to match one or more space, you can do all this with Pattern

```
String text = "Your Day Traffic is 150 MB and your Night Traffic is 136 MB ";
String regex = "((\\d+)\\sMB)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
int group = 1;
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("group " + group++ + " ==> " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

In your case outputs are :

```
group 1 ==> 150
group 2 ==> 136
```

Comment: @Logan what did you mean not work at all, can you explain?

Comment: this regex can't find number

Comment: check this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RiPS0b/1/) and check the [code demo](https://ideone.com/xsxWRi)

Comment: @Logan maybe for a better way, and to insure to get only one or two result you can use this way instead [second solution](https://ideone.com/GF7CfE)

Answer (score 0):

Please read the java docs on regex [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Essentially you have to ignore character between two "[number] MB" occurences. In that situation you can use a regex like so -

```
/.*\s+(\d+)\s+MB.*\s+(\d+)\s+MB/
```

Full code is given here -

```
import java.util.regex.*;  

public class MatchMB {  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\s+(\\d+)\\s+MB.*\\s+(\\d+)\\s+MB");  
  Matcher m = p.matcher("Your Day Traffic is 150 MB and your Night Traffic is 136 MB");  

  while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("group 1 ==>" + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("group 2 ==>" + m.group(2));
  }
}
```

Comment: sometimes second number(136)is not exist , so i cant get first number; how i can fix it?

"Your Day Traffic is 150 MB and don't have Night Traffic"

Comment: Please ask a separate question if you have a new problem.